Finding the law of a Brownian motion triple
Let $B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $S_{s,t} = \sup_{s \leq r \leq t} B_r$. It is well known from a classic result of Lévy that $S_{0,t} - B_t$ realises a Brownian motion reflecting above $0$. Given this, it may be useful to know the joint law $(B_t, S_{0,t})$. This is also known (see page 27 of Itô and McKean's book 'Diffusion Processes and their Sample Paths') and the joint density function is given by $$f(t;b,s)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi t^3}}(2s-b)e^{-\frac{(2s-b)^2}{2t}}.$$ If instead of just dealing with a Brownian motion reflected above $0$ we are dealing with a Brownian motion reflected between say $0$ and $1$, then we have (from (1.8) in the paper 'Double Skorokhod map and reneging real-time queues' by Kruk, L., Lehoczky, J., Ramanan, K. and Shreve, S.) that $$S_{0,t} \wedge \inf_{s \in [0,t]} [(1+B_s) \vee S_{s,t}]-B_t $$ realises this Brownian motion reflected between $0$ and $1$. Given this it may then instead be useful to know the joint law of the triple $(B_t, S_{0,t}, I_t)$ where $I_t = \inf_{s \in [0,t]} [(1+B_s) \vee S_{s,t}]$. I've been trying to work out if any applications of the reflection principle are possible to find this but am struggling as I'm finding the process $I_t$ quite hard to visualise, but does anyone know if such a result for the law of this triple or a similar result exists anywhere? Just wondering as the function $I_t$ itself looks quite unique, but a Brownian motion reflected between two boundaries has been considered a lot?
